# List the index which are not created by primary key

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query which will display all the Indexes present in the schema except those which are created when a primary key is created.
I tried with `select * from all_indexes` it will list all the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to display the indexes of the current db-user you can query user_indexes and user_constraints

```
select index_name from user_indexes
minus
select  index_name from user_constraints where constraint_type = 'P';
```

to display the indexes of the all schemas use the all_... dictionary views

```
select owner, index_name from all_indexes
minus
select owner, index_name from all_constraints where constraint_type = 'P';
```

Comment: I believe it's safer to consider even the schema name, not only the index name

Comment: @Aleksej: you are absolutely right, i have edit my answer

Comment: Thank you @schurik and Aleksej